# IdentityCache v0.5.0 returns only readonly object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord, readonly

I was using identity_cache(https://github.com/Shopify/identity_cache) v0.3.2 and updated today to v0.5.0. 
but after I updated, every object fetched is marked as 'readonly'

```
bm = Bizmodel.fetch 1
bm.agree = false
bm.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord: Bizmodel is marked as readonly
```

It may be desinged(https://github.com/Shopify/identity_cache/issues/274)...

Is there any option to fetch object for writing? 
or any other nice work-around to update object fetched by identity_cache?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do away with the protection that IdentityCache added to guarantee only a database-fetched object can be updated, you can add this into your bootstrapping process (in an initializer for Rails):

`IdentityCache.fetch_read_only_records = false`

[Here's](https://github.com/Shopify/identity_cache/issues/274) a discussion about the addition of the feature.